# Insert attribute's value of checkboxes to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have multiple checkboxes in form with values like this

```
<input type="checkbox" value="100400020719-006" name="selected" class="inforID" id="ABS-02072019" plant="VDNF" flowno="FLW-000001">
```

When checkbox is checked, and button is pressed, I will get attributes and insert into input with id `arr`

```
<input type="hidden" id="arr" name="arr" /> 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnConf").click(function(){
        var selected = [];
        $.each($("input[name='selected']:checked"), function () {
            selected.push($(this).val(), $(this).attr("id"), $(this).attr("plant"), $(this).attr("flowno"));
            document.getElementById("arr").value = selected;
        });
        console.log(selected);
    });
});
```

But the array which I get is

```
<input type="hidden" id="arr" name="arr" value="100400020719-006,ABS-02072019,VDNF,FLW-000001,100400020719-007,ABS-02072019,VDNF,FLW-000001">
```

How can I get the array like this:

```
[
    {
        "DocNo":"100400020719-006",
        "NewDocNo":"ABS-02072019",
        "Plant":"VDNF",
        "FlowNow":"FLW-000001"
    },
    {
        "DocNo":"100400020719-007",
        "NewDocNo":"ABS-02072019",
        "Plant":"VDNF",
        "FlowNow":"FLW-000001"
    }
]
```

Or like this

```
[
    {
        "100400020719-006",
        "ABS-02072019",
        "VDNF",
        "FLW-000001"
    },
    {
        "100400020719-007",
        "ABS-02072019",
        "VDNF",
        "FLW-000001"
    }
]
```

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `stringify` your data and set it in hidden box. and you can `parse` and use wherever you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnConf").click(function(){
        var selected = [];
        $.each($("input[name='selected']:checked"), function () {
            selected.push({
              "DocNo": $(this).val(),
              "NewDocNo": $(this).attr("id"),
              "Plant": $(this).attr("plant"),
              "FlowNow": $(this).attr("flowno")
            });
            $("#arr").val(JSON.stringify(selected));
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(selected));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="100400020719-006" name="selected" class="inforID" id="ABS-02072019" plant="VDNF" flowno="FLW-000001">

<input type="checkbox" value="100400020719-007" name="selected" class="inforID" id="ABS-02072018" plant="VDND" flowno="FLW-000002">

<input type="hidden" id="arr" name="arr" />

<input type="button" value="get" id="btnConf"/>
```

Comment: thank you very much, I have tried this solution but not convert array to JSON.

Comment: I can't get you. are you saying you don't want to convert it to JSON?

Comment: I mean I have tried this solution before but not use JSON.stringify, so I didn't get the array

Answer (score 1):

insert selected checkbox attribute values as [JS objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp) into `selected`
 array

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnConf").click(function() {
    var selected = [];
    $.each($("input[name='selected']:checked"), function() {
      selected.push({
        "DocNo": $(this).val(),
        "NewDocNo": $(this).attr("id"),
        "Plant": $(this).attr("plant"),
        "FlowNow": $(this).attr("flowno")
      });
      document.getElementById("arr").value = selected;
    });
    console.log(selected);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Push your information as an object into `selected` array. At the end of processing use `JSON.stringify` to change the object into string and store it in the hidden variable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var selected = [];
  $("#btnConf").click(function() {
    selected = [];
    $.each($("input[name='selected']:checked"), function() {
      selected.push({
        DocNo: $(this).val(),
        NewDocNo: $(this).attr("id"),
        Plant: $(this).attr("plant"),
        FlowNow: $(this).attr("flowno")
      });
    });
    $("#arr").val(JSON.stringify(selected));
    console.log($("#arr").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="100400020719-006" name="selected" class="inforID" id="ABS-02072019" plant="VDNF" flowno="FLW-000001">
<input type="checkbox" value="100400020719-006" name="selected" class="inforID" id="ABS-02072019" plant="VDNF" flowno="FLW-000001">
<button id="btnConf">Configure</button>
<input type="hidden" id="arr" name="arr" />
```